# Regex. How to get multiple matches from this string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using javascript regex.
Let's say I have the following string:

```
XXX_1_XXX XXX_2_XXX XXX_3_XXX YYY_1_YYY YYY_2_YYY YYY_3_YYY
```

and I'd like to run a regex and get a result with this pattern:

```
Match1
1.    XXX_1_XXX
2.    YYY_1_YYY
Match2
1.    XXX_2_XXX
2.    YYY_2_YYY
Match3
1.    XXX_3_XXX
2.    YYY_3_YYY
```

I have tried variations of this:

```
/(XXX_(.)_XXX)(.)*?(YYY_\2_YYY)/g
```

but it stops at the first match only.

Is there any way to do this with regex? or I am better off iterating over it as an array?

Comment: Well you could simply cut of the part of the string where the match starts...

Comment: It does not look to me like you can get those matches with one pass with one single regex.  Once you've matched past something, it doesn't go backwards to find another match.

Comment: Get all the matches at once: `/([XY]{3}_[0-3]_[XY]{3})/g`. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/xS9eA5/1

Comment: The way regex works is that it tries to match something, then when the g flag is set, it starts behind the first match. In your case it starts again behind `YYY_1_YYY` and obviously there is no match there. May I ask what the underlying problem is you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Sumurai8: you can circumvent this problem, by implementing a (modified) globalizer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matches are iterative over the string, the regex only searcher for more matches **after** the end of the previous match. This guarantees progress since empty strings can result in an infinite loop.

But you can solve this problem as follows:

```
var text = "XXX_1_XXX XXX_2_XXX XXX_3_XXX YYY_1_YYY YYY_2_YYY YYY_3_YYY";
var re = /(XXX_(.)_XXX)(.)*?(YYY_\2_YYY)/;
while((m = re.exec(text)) !== null) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(m));//the result (print)
    //do something with m
    text = text.substring(m.index+1); //this is not the same as /g
    // "/g" would be text = text.substring(m.index+m[0].length+1);
}
```

The program works as follows: you **don't use** the `/g` modifier, so only one match is done.

1. Each iteration, you **try to match** the string with the regex.
2. In case it matches, you determine the `.index` where the match starts and drop the string (inclusively) up to that point
3. you repeat the search with the modified string until that string can't find convergence as well.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kommusoft/5bjqr31t/).

> **Note**: there is one case where this might fail: if the empty string can be matched as well, since at the end of the string, it will keep matching the empty string and cutting will result in another empty string. It's however easy to implement a zero-length-check. This issue does not occur with [@Ja͢ck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27886420/67579).

> **Note**: another aspect that one must take into account is that this doesn't require "global" progression. The string `XXX_1_XXX XXX_2_XXX XXX_3_XXX YYY_1_YYY YYY_3_YYY YYY_2_YYY` (mind the swapped values in the `YYY_|_YYYY` part), will give the same result.

Comment: Yes thank you, this solves it. As others have pointed, I was having trouble because the cursor would start after the first match. The while loop solves it.

Comment: @han4wluc: as noted in the answer, there is a good reason why this happens, if empty strings can be matched, you must be more careful.

Answer (score 2):

The website regex101.com is a great resource for figuring out the right regular expression. I've prepared two examples:

`/([XY]{3}_[0-3]_[XY]{3})/g`

will return:

> MATCH 1
>   1.    [0-9]   `XXX_1_XXX`
>   MATCH 2
>   1.    [10-19] `XXX_2_XXX`
>   MATCH 3
>   1.    [20-29] `XXX_3_XXX`
>   MATCH 4
>   1.    [30-39] `YYY_1_YYY`
>   MATCH 5
>   1.    [40-49] `YYY_2_YYY`
>   MATCH 6
>   1.    [50-59] `YYY_3_YYY`

https://regex101.com/r/xS9eA5/1

and

`/(?:([XY]{3}_[0-3]_[XY]{3}) ([XY]{3}_[0-3]_[XY]{3}))/g`

will return:

> MATCH 1
>   1.    [0-9]   `XXX_1_XXX`
>   2.    [10-19] `XXX_2_XXX`
>   MATCH 2
>   1.    [20-29] `XXX_3_XXX`
>   2.    [30-39] `YYY_1_YYY`
>   MATCH 3
>   1.    [40-49] `YYY_2_YYY`
>   2.    [50-59] `YYY_3_YYY`

https://regex101.com/r/xS9eA5/2

Comment: This will also match strings like `XYX_1_XYX` though.

Comment: If such edge cases exist, the regular expression should be updated indeed. It also does not group the strings as `XXX_1_XXX`and `YYY_1_YYY` as requested, but that's next to impossible with a regular expression if the sorting is not done before parsing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I needed XXX_1_XXX and YYY_1_YYY to be in the same match. (the ones with the same number)

Comment: You think you need them both in the same match, but if you alter the first regex slightly so that the match contains `1_XXX` and `1_YYY` you simply sort the list and that way have an easy time grouping them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that after the first match, the internal index of the regular expression engine is set right after the "YYY_*_YYY".

Luckily, within the loop you can move that position to right after the "XXX_*_XXX" match instead:

```
var s = 'XXX_1_XXX XXX_2_XXX XXX_3_XXX YYY_1_YYY YYY_2_YYY YYY_3_YYY';
var re = /(XXX_(\d)_XXX).*?(YYY_\2_YYY)/g;

while ((match = re.exec(s)) !== null) {
  console.log(match[1], match[3]);
  // move to start of last match plus length of first submatch
  re.lastIndex = match.index + match[1].length;
}
```

#### Output

```
"XXX_1_XXX"
"YYY_1_YYY"

"XXX_2_XXX"
"YYY_2_YYY"

"XXX_3_XXX"
"YYY_3_YYY"
```

Comment: I suppose, except that this doesn't require substrings.

Comment: another thing is that you use group `[1]`. For this example, that will work since there is no overlap, but in a general case, it can lead to conflicts. For instance for `/(aaa)/` and `aaaa` on expects two matches.

Comment: You can't always consider all the angles.

Comment: well a small mod to `re.lastIndex = match.index+1;` fixes this *"issue"*.