# How to search part of a text

Tags: python-3.x

I need to capture part of a text within several other texts and within these several texts I have some that always have the same initial and final word, how can I do that?

I trying make a program to search part of the a text, in the text I have a key initial and a final key.

The text format is this:

> my random text this my random text this my random text this my random
> text this my random text this **MY_START_WORD_KEY my text this my text
> this my text this my text this my text this MY_END_WORD_KEY** my random text this my random text this my random text this my random text this my random text this **MY_START_WORD_KEY my text this my text
> this my text this my text this my text this MY_END_WORD_KEY** my random text this my random text this my random text this my random text this my random text this

I created this code:

```
txt = "my_text.txt"

with open(txt, encoding="utf8") as text:
    all_text = text.read()



start='START MY KEY WORD '
end='END MY KEY WORD'
result=[]
temp=all_text.split(start)
for part in temp:
    if end in part:
        result.append(part.split(end)[0])
```

But that way the initial and final word is lost in my final full text.
I need everything between the initial keyword to the final keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like

```py
import re

txt = '''my random text this my random text this my random text this my random text this my random text this START_KEY my text this my text this my text this my text this my text this END_KEY my text this my text this my text this my text this my text this my text this my text this
more random START_KEY text END_KEY.'''

START_KEY='START_KEY'
END_KEY='END_KEY'
matches = re.findall(START_KEY+r"\s.*\s"+END_KEY, txt)
```

the result will be

```py
matches = ['START_KEY my text this my text this my text this my text this my text this END_KEY',
 'START_KEY text END_KEY']
```

Regex can be very useful for things like this,
you can find more about 're' lib [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry I did some tests and a new problem arose, I ended up editing the example text here. in this link is one of the tests I did with the regex: [LINK](https://regex101.com/r/hkhPHe/1) and I think the regex will not work because to create multiple matches I need to pass the specific size of what I want to capture [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886099/regex-how-to-get-multiple-matches-from-this-string). In this [example](https://regex101.com/r/hkhPHe/1) the correct would be 3 match/groups

Comment: Oh, I see. The problem is that the regex matches the "largest pattern" on each line. 
In some documentations, you will find this behavior as "greedy match". There are more than one way to solve this, the best is to change the ".*" in regex to a "nongready" version, like [this](https://regex101.com/r/zctQqO/1).

In python code will be just
```matches = re.findall(START_KEY+r"\s.*?\s"+END_KEY, txt)```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only see one occurrence of the start and end word in the text:

```py
text = ...
start="start"
end="end"

result = text.split(start)[1].split(end)[0].strip()
```

You can split and select the middle portion.

Comment: it keeps cutting the word in variable 'START' and 'END'

Comment: You can simply amend that by adding the start and end respectively to the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
keys = ['start','end']
text = "Everything between key[0] and key[1]+3 is suposed to return as substring. start extracting here and stop at the end. This part should not appear in extracted substring."

start = text.index(keys[0])
end = text.index(keys[1])

print(text[:start], '\n', text[start:end+3], '\n', text[end+3:])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry, doing some testing with the solutions posted here, I had a problem and edited the example text here, as there may be several occurrences that I need to capture

Answer (score 0):

Tô kee START and END words, use a regexp like:

`/(START.*END)/gm`

To remove the limiting words,nuse the following regexp:

`/START(.*)END/gm`

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry I did some tests and a new problem arose, I ended up editing the example text here. in this link is one of the tests I did with the regex: [LINK](https://regex101.com/r/hkhPHe/1) and I think the regex will not work because to create multiple matches I need to pass the specific size of what I want to capture [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886099/regex-how-to-get-multiple-matches-from-this-string). In this [example](https://regex101.com/r/hkhPHe/1) the correct would be 3 match/groups